# How to make AT command to automatically return caller ID?

Tags: matlab, at-command

So, I'm using AT Commands with Matlab to return the Caller ID. It DOES work, but I have to manually ask for it. I what it to return Caller ID automatically whenever I ring on the phone.

Here is what I write before I ring:

```
>> s = serial('COM8');
>> fopen(s)
```

And I type this when my phone rings:

```
 >> fwrite(s, [65 84 43 67 82 67 61 49 13])
```

Then I ask for the returned value(the caller phone number):

```
   >> s

   Serial Port Object : Serial-COM8

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM8
      BaudRate:           9600
      Terminator:         'LF'

   Communication State 
      Status:             open
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     47
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         18

   >> fread(s, 47)
```

and it returns me 47 ASCII numbers like this(note that I have deleted most of the returned code):

```
ans =

    65
    84
    43
    67
    82
    67
    61
    49
    13
```

Which translates to the following(changed the number for safety reasons):

```
+CRING:VOICE +CLIP: "+359888888888",145AT+CRC=1OK
```

What I want to happen is when the phone rings to immediately send the computer the output of

```
 >> fwrite(s, [65 84 43 67 82 67 61 49 13])
 >> fread(s, 47)
```

Comment: Can your computer have any indication that the phone rings (the "how" is irrelevant to this question)? Alternatively, does the phone send automatically something over the serial to indicate that it's ringing?

Comment: I have no idea how to answer your question, but I'd love to know more about how you're connecting MATLAB up to your phone.

Comment: @EitanT The phone doesn't send any automatic message, that's what I want it to do. Nothing happens on the computer when somebody rings on my phone.

Comment: @SamRoberts, you connect the phone to the computer, check which COM port it's using and then you type in the commands above (or google AT commands for more of those)

Comment: @r0Lf Conceptually, how do you want your computer to respond to something if it is never notified of it? You can try periodic polling, but I think that's not what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: @EitanT, that's the problem. I do not know how to make my phone notify the computer that somebody is ringing. Periodic polling won't really help me.

Comment: @r0LF then it's not really a MATLAB question, is it?